# Error with Conditional Rendering

Tags: lightning-web-components

I can get the status to be green but when the status is rejected it still shows green and does not show the additional field. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

```
<template>
    <lightning-card
        title="Status">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <p><lightning-formatted-text class={color} value={status} onchange={handleChange}>
                </lightning-formatted-text></p>
            </div>
        <template if:true={isRejected}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <p><lightning-formatted-text value={rejected} onchange={handleChange}>
                </lightning-formatted-text></p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Status__c';
import REJ_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Reason_for_Rejection__c';

let fields = [STATUS_FIELD, REJ_FIELD];

export default class DisplayStatus extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track color = 'good';
    @track isRejected = false;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    application__c;

    get status(){
        return getFieldValue(this.application__c.data, STATUS_FIELD);
    }
    get rejected(){ 
        return getFieldValue(this.application__c.data, REJ_FIELD);}

    handleChange(){
    if (this.status === 'Rejected') {
        this.color = 'bad';
        this.isRejected = this.event.target.value;
    }else{
        this.color = 'good';
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
.good{
    color: green;
}
.bad{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onchange` event for `lightning-formatted-text`. As such, the `handleChange` function is never called. Instead, you could react to the change in the wire adapter.

```
@track application__c = {};

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
getRecordHandler({data,error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.application__c = data;
    switch(getFieldValue(data, STATUS_FIELD)) {
      case 'Rejected':
        this.color = 'bad';
        this.isRejected = true;
        break;
      default:
        this.color = 'good';
        this.isRejected = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to find this information about what events are available to which components in the documentation?

Comment: @JenniferPrather For now, it appears you need to check the "Aura" version of the docs. I'm not sure why the events are missing in the LWC docs. However, mostly all you need to remember is that only inputs can change. Output elements do not "change" in that sense, as the change event represents the user changing data, and not changes from any other source or script.

Comment: This did not work like intended. I inspected the lwc using the dev tools in the org. It is still saying the class is good even when it is rejected.